# Android Navigational Drawer activate w/ button

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingdrawer

since i am quite new to Android i am trying to create a Navigational Drawer that gets activated when pressing a button. I checked several tutorials like this [one](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/06/android-sliding-navigation-drawer-example.html) but in all of them the drawer gets activated when an Actionbar button is pressed. One more thing. My activity consists of 3 buttons and an image so i use RelativeLayout, how can i add a FrameLayout to RelativeLayout? Should i change it?

Can someone work something out so i can get the general idea?
Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the XML element (e.g. Button, or TextView) put:

```
android:onClick="onBtnClick"
```

In the linked Activity add the method:

```
public void onBtnClick(View view) {
    //open the drawer as a menu
    View mFragmentContainerView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
}
```

You can simply drag a FrameLayout into a RelativeLayout, so I do not understand your issue there.